# When pressing coffee, why does boiling water and coffee mixture appear to decrease after grounds are pressed to bottom?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, everyday-life, water, granulated-materials

When pressing coffee, why does total volume of boiling water and coffee appear to decrease after grounds are pressed to bottom?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a question about physics

Comment: I think this is a great physics question.  If you want to add some jargon, you could talk about "packing of granular media", but the physics is the same with or without the lingo.

Answer (score 1):

the ground coffee contains air, so you press the air out.So it's not a physic question, but just knowing, what a sponge does.